# Java OOP Why doesn't the function see variable?

Tags: java, oop

I am pretty new to coding and I have been having trouble with a Physics calculator I've been making. I made this trying to utilize OOP for a class project. The point I to let the user input the variables, then they get shipped into the equation on the class file, and then finally display the result. When I try to compile, it says that the function getAnswer can't see the result declared above it. I plan to make each of the 16 iterations of the equation, so I need to first figure out why this one doesn't work. Any answer is welcome.

-Thanks

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class VFD {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Kinmatics calculator");
        System.out.println("You can find Final Velocity, Acceleration, DIsplacemnt, or Time");
        System.out.println("What variable is not included in the equation?");
        String missing = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("What variable are you looking for?");
        String find = keyboard.next();
        
        
        if (missing.equals("Final Velocity") && find.equals("Initial Velocity")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your available values");
        System.out.println("Acceleration = (m/s^2)");
        double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Displacement = (m)");
        double d = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Time = (s)");
        double t = keyboard.nextDouble();
        VelocityFinder qviadt = new VelocityFinder();
        qviadt.qviadt(a, d, t); 
        System.out.println(qviadt.getAnswer());
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the class file

```
public class VelocityFinder {
    
    public void qviadt( double a, double d, double t  ) {
        double result = d/(.5*a*(t*t))/t;
        double answer = result;
    }
    public String getAnswer () {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class VelocityFinder {
    private double answer;

    
    public void qviadt( double a, double d, double t  ) {
        double result = d/(.5*a*(t*t))/t;
        double answer = result;
    }
    public String getAnswer () {
        return String.valueOf(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the variable answer is in the function qviadt(),getAnswer can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `qviadt` and `getAnswer` are in the same class, but they are not the same method. `getAnswer` is trying to return something that doesn't exist. To fix this, remove `getAnswer` and change `qviadt` to:

```
public void qviadt( double a, double d, double t  ) {
    double result = d/(.5*a*(t*t))/t;
    double answer = result;
    return answer;
}
```

and store the return value of it directly. This is called a scope issue and you should look into what scope is and how to use it.

Comment: Your code has an issue. You are returning the double answer when the method has a void declaration meaning the method should not have a return statement.